# Fillable Pdf multi-line, Allow rich text formatting in Acrobat Pro DC: but it ignores line spacing/leading set in More

Tags: forms, pdf, acrobat, line-spacing, fillable

I'm on Win10, using Acrobat Pro DC 2021.011... to edit and Reader DC (same version) to test.
From experience and from reading forums etc, forms in these apps are maddening... but I have not been able to find any discussion (or solutions) to the following behavior...

The form I'm building for other employees' use has a large edit text box set to Multi-line and Allow Rich Text Formatting. It is set to a default font, Calibri and size 50pt. For most situations this will work for them; provides 2-3 lines for a short product description. But occasionally they want a smaller font and more lines... They know how to get the ctrl+e properties bar. But in my testing of this alternative situation they'll need sometimes, I'm finding it's impossible to get the smaller font size and more lines to work. Here's my process.

1. tab into text box. Ctrl+E for properties bar.
   [image: form field with cursor in and ready to type and stylize]
2. before typing I set the font size to 24
3. then I type in my 4 lines of text
   [image: text in place set to desired font size - lines spacing great]
4. then I tab to my next form field...
5. and kaboom... the field I just filled...it's line height is so large it's pushed some of the content invisible. I assume this is coming from the field's default font size, 50
   [image: wacky leading after tabbing to next field]
6. **And** if I try to adjust the line height, by selecting all the text and then choosing in More...>Form Field Text Properties>Paragraph>Line Spacing
   [image: text set to line height single, 24pt font size]
7. If I set it to Single and click Close/click into another field I get the very large leading (presumably for 50pt font (same as pic above after point 5)
8. If I choose Exactly and set to point size slightly larger, click Close/out of field, I get another ridiculous result where the 2/3 line have the height I set, but the space between the 1 & 2 second line is way too much and the space between the last line and 3rd line is way too small...
   [image: text set to 24pt font size and 27pt line height Looks Great!]
   **before tabbing or clicking out of field to another field**

[image: terrible result... not usuable]
Good lord.. what is that! 3 different leading values in the same field; just after applying 1 value to all lines, all text in the field...

It makes no sense... it doesn't look like it regards your input at all, and just comes up with it's own random leading... I've fiddled with Space before/after and combinations of Line Height and nothing comes close to what we need... At this point I'm convinced the Acrobat tools for a stylizing text in a multi-line, allow formatting text field are useless. I'd be better off with my employees they can't format anything, ever. Just type one line and hit Tab or Enter...

What is going on! I'm trying to make a simple fillable form for other employees to use, but this kind of behavior makes that impossible (It's enough of a stretch to teach them to use the ctrl+E and do some styling of their text but this is bonkers and completely unteachable... there's not rhyme or pattern to teach!)

Hope someone can help or has seen this behavior too.

Comment: Ah... that might explain the clunkiness of it...  Do you know what people use today (moved on to something better) or has everyone given up on styling multiline boxes like this because of Adobe laziness (or incompetence or more benign reasons) and therefore I need to rethink whole design so I don't need a text box like this?